# Disable subframes(iframes) loading in PhantomJs/QtWebKit

Tags: iframe, webkit, phantomjs, qtwebkit

Is there any way to disable loading subframes in phantomJs or even QtWebKit/webkit in general?
i have no problem massing a bit with the source code if it is necessary.
I'm doing some web manipulation but i don't need the contents of iframes, it only slows down the loading time.

I know it can be done in Mozilla for example.

```
webSetup->SetProperty(nsIWebBrowserSetup::SETUP_ALLOW_SUBFRAMES,PR_TRUE);
```

But so far i didn't find anything in QtWebKit to do this.

maybe is there's a way using **onResourceRequested** to block only requests for iframes ?

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work:

```
// load only the main page, no iframes
page.onLoadStarted = function() {
        page.navigationLocked = true;
};
```

Could unlock it again after the page loads, if necessary.

Alternatively, can use this to block loading any resources:

```
var req_count = 0;
page.onResourceRequested = function(requestData, networkRequest) {
        if (req_count++ > 0) {
                networkRequest.abort();
        }
}
```

See also:

http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-requested.html
http://newspaint.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/adblock-for-phantomjs/